# Multiple configuration files with Python ConfigParser

Tags: python, configuration

When calling ConfigParser.read you are allowed to pass a list of strings corresponding to potential locations for configuration files and the function returns a list of those files that were successfully read.

What is the default behaviour when multiple configuration files are loaded that have overlapping sections/keys? Do later files in the list override values parsed by earlier ones? Is the entire section overridden or just conflicting keys?

Comment: Have you tried creating and reading multiple config files to see what would happen?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

After getting around to testing it, ConfigParser overwrites the keys with each successive file, the order in which the files are read is determined by the order of the file names in the list passed to ConfigParser.read

Answer (score 35):

Just to give an example for further detail.

I can create the following two files:
`config1.ini`

```
# ** config1.ini **
[shared]
prop_uniue1 = 1
prop_shared = 10

[unique1]
test_unique = 101
```

and `config2.ini`:

```
# ** config2.ini **
[shared]
prop_uniue2 = 2
prop_shared = 14

[unique2]
test_unique = 102
```

Then if I run the following I can see how the configs get updated (outputs are shown as comments after the respective print statements):

```
import ConfigParser

config = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
config.read(['config1.ini', 'config2.ini'])


print config.sections() # ['shared', 'unique1', 'unique2']
print config.get("shared", "prop_uniue1")  # 1
print config.get("shared", "prop_shared")  # 14
print config.get("unique1", "test_unique") # 101

print config.get("shared", "prop_uniue2")  # 2
print config.get("unique2", "test_unique") # 102
```

So to summarise it would appear:

- as [crasic says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4057933/866022) the order in which the files are read is determined by the order in which the file names appear in the list given to the read method,
- the keys are overwritten by later files but this is done at the lower option level rather than the higher section level. This means that if you have options that do not occur in later files even if the section does occur then the options from the earlier files will be used.

Comment: Nice example. Most of the literature I have seen about `ConfigParser` completely miss out on the ability to layer the config settings using multiple files.  

This is very similar to how  `.NET Core App` settings handles . They go a step ahead and allow for config values to come in from environment variables  and other custom sources.

Think of a master `settings.json` and then environment specific settings file , `settings-dev.json` or `setttings-uat.json` or `settings-prod.json` loaded dynamically by determining the value of an environment variable .